# Probability Of Timed Events

Tags: probability

I work in a call center and I am currently writing new scripts that will process our calls. We have two methods of playing methods, one of which waits a specified amount of time for a group of callers who need to hear the samemessage and the second which instantly plays the message to a caller on a 121 basis. The second is more favourable as there is no delay waiting for the message to be played. We are however limited to having 14 voice ports open at any one time. If these are maxed then the caller will queue for the next available port to be available.

I want to try and calculate the probability of a caller having to queue for a message if I was to use the preferred option.

We receive on average 200 calls per hour.
Calls wait an average of 50 seconds to be answered.
Whilst a call is waiting a message is played every 30 seconds.
The average length of a message is 10 seconds.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to calculating this?

Many Thanks
Matt

Comment: That's an average of 10 000 seconds waiting to be answered per hour?  (200 * 50)? As there are 3600 seconds in an hour i'd say you expect 100/36 callers waiting at a singular moment, and that number of callers is probably poisson distributed.  So I think the number of callers is (roughly) distributed as P(3)...  I think you need some testing te check the validity of this...  but it might be a good way to start